# Convert HTML string to Markdown in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, discord

I'm building a Google Apps Script (GAS) project to read email (from gmail) and forward it to a Discord channel. This is working ... but Discord can't display HTML.

It's possible to just get the plain text version of an email in GAS but that loses all the nice links, text formatting etc. SO, I figured I could parse the HTML email contents to markdown before posting it.

How best to achieve this?

**What I've tried**

**[Turndown](https://github.com/mixmark-io/turndown)** exists to convert between the formats but will fail in a GAS script in the `createHTMLParser` function as it assumes it's running in a browser (`window` and `document` are both undefined).

**[htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2)** looks like it could be a drop-in alternative parser that can give me a DOM (from it's DOMUtils module) but is non-trivial, has a bunch of dependencies. I don't see how I can use this in a GAS without a lot of copying code, and then needing to convert the .ts content to .gs via **[clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp)**.

Comment: You're probably not using turndown correctly, it's [meant to work with nodejs](https://github.com/mixmark-io/turndown#usage).